# Is there any crossplatform C library for using Pixel Shading filters?

Tags: c, filter, cross-platform, pixel-shading

Is there any crossplatform C library for using Pixel Shading filters? to run pixel shader inside your programm, beter as native part of your programm (not like precompiled file), and better for using with abstract data - not only images

Comment: What else do you plan to "shade", besides images?

Comment: could you provide more detail? (Is something like OpenCL(http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want? http://www.khronos.org/opencl/ The question is not very detailed, or clear, but I think OpenCL qualifies as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL or CUDA are the closest to what you want.